# Proper construction of Django Model

Tags: django, model

I'm creating a tracking application for exercise and I'm wondering about the most efficient way to create the models.  Most exercises I do have repetitions, sets, and weights.  But then there are runs which have distances and times.  At first, I was going to create two different models to capture each, but then I thought it might be better to combine then.  Now, I'm not sure.

Ok, below is my first pass:

```
LEVELS = (
    (1, '1 - Hardly'),
    (2, '2'),
    (3, '3'),
    (4, '4'),
    (5, '5 - Average'),
    (6, '6'),
    (7, '7'),
    (8, '8'),
    (9, '9'),
    (10, '10 - Very'),

class Jog(models.Model):
    distance = models.DecimalField("Distance (Miles)", max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
    time = models.DecimalField("Time (Minutes)", max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
    intensity = models.IntegerField("Intensity", choices = LEVELS, default = 5)
    date = models.DateTimeField("Date", blank=True, default=datetime.now)   
    notes = models.TextField("Notes", blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s Miles in %s Minutes (Intensity of %s)" % (self.distance, self.time, self.intensity)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Jog"

class Exercise_Type(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Exercise Name", max_length=200, unique = True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    notes = models.TextField("Notes", blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Workout(models.Model):
    exercise_type = models.ForeignKey(Exercise_Type, verbose_name="Exercise Type")
    reps = models.IntegerField("Repetitions")
    sets = models.DecimalField("Sets", max_digits=2, decimal_places=1)
    weight = models.IntegerField("Weight", blank=True, null=True)
    intensity = models.IntegerField("Intensity", choices = LEVELS, default = 5)
    date = models.DateTimeField("Date", blank=True, default=datetime.now)
    notes = models.TextField("Notes", blank=True)
```

This seemed silly though because a jog is a type of workout and is only getting split out because it has different measurement characteristics.  So then I thought, what if I do something like this.  Define the necessary fields in the workout type and then enable/suppress them by asking the user the Exercise Type:

```
class Exercise_Type(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Exercise Name", max_length=200, unique = True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    notes = models.TextField("Notes", blank=True)

    distance = models.BooleanField("Use Distance Field?", default = False)
    time = models.BooleanField("Use Time Field?", default = False)
    reps = models.BooleanField("Use Reps Field", default = False)
    sets = models.BooleanField("Use Sets Field?", default = False)
    weight = models.BooleanField("Use Weight Field?", default = False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Workout(models.Model):
    exercise_type = models.ForeignKey(Exercise_Type, verbose_name="Exercise Type")
    distance = models.DecimalField("Distance (Miles)", max_digits=4, decimal_places=2, blank = True, null=True)
    time = models.DecimalField("Time (Minutes)", max_digits=4, decimal_places=2, blank = True, null=True)
    reps = models.IntegerField("Repetitions", blank = True, null=True)
    sets = models.DecimalField("Sets", max_digits=2, decimal_places=1, blank = True, null=True)
    weight = models.IntegerField("Weight", blank=True, null=True)
    intensity = models.IntegerField("Intensity", choices = LEVELS, default = 5)
    date = models.DateTimeField("Date", blank=True, default=datetime.now)
    notes = models.TextField("Notes", blank=True)
```

This seems like a waste of resources because every exercise will technically have every field regardless of whether it needs it or not.

Then I thought, what about sub-classing?  That's when I gave up and decided to appeal to those more knowledgeable than myself.

What's the best way to organize this model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each exercise has one or more properties that you want to measure, you should extract those properties out, so you end up with three main models.

```
class Metric(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
   measured_in = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
   # other fields

class Measurement(models.Model):
   metric = models.ForeignKey(Metric)
   value = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
   workout_date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

class Workout(models.Model):
   # common attributes for each workout
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   notes = models.TextField()
   metrics = models.ManyToManyField(Measurement)
```

You add various metrics (things you measure) to `Metric`. For each workout, you identify which metric you want to track, by adding creating a new `Measurement`. Finally, you associate it to each workout when you create it.

Here is a sample:

```
reps = Metric.objects.create(name='Reps')
my_reps = Measurement.objects.create(metric=reps,value=10)
w = Workout(name="Weights")
w.metrics.add(my_reps)
w.save()
```

Comment: +1, though shouldn't workout_date be part of workout, instead of Measurement

Comment: You can have it in both places, so a workout (or a workout regiment) can span multiple dates, and you do certain exercises on each date.

Comment: but usually workouts would be for each day, separate day workouts should be listed separately, otherwise there would be only one workout row

Comment: Interesting solution.  Ok, so here's a question.  In terms of standardization, when I'm entering, say benchpress, it should ALWAYS include weight, reps, and sets.  How would I standardize the input?  Would I create a form for each workout type that includes these three metrics?  Otherwise it might be too freeform.

Comment: You would first add weight, reps and sets in Metrics, then add the three to Workout with no value. When you display the Workout form, you display the metrics as inlines.

Comment: Good points on both solutions (Burhan Khalid's and Chris Pratt's).  Going with this Burhan's solution because it is easy to generalize for tracking activities outside of exercises.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what inheritance is made for. Create a generic `Workout` type, and then subclass it with the types of workouts. With the unique/specific attributes on the subclasses.

```
class Workout(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField("Date", blank=True, default=datetime.now)
    notes = models.TextField("Notes", blank=True)

class Jog(Workout):
    distance = models.DecimalField("Distance (Miles)", max_digits=4, decimal_places=2, blank = True, null=True)
    time = models.DecimalField("Time (Minutes)", max_digits=4, decimal_places=2, blank = True, null=True)

class Weightlifting(Workout):
    reps = models.IntegerField("Repetitions", blank = True, null=True)
    sets = models.DecimalField("Sets", max_digits=2, decimal_places=1, blank = True, null=True)
    weight = models.IntegerField("Weight", blank=True, null=True)
```

And so on. If you don't need to use the generic `Workout` type anywhere, you can make it an abstract model.

Comment: I thought about this at first, but it doesn't allow for easy adding for different workouts without doing database migrations. You'd have to know all your workouts in advance, which may not be practical.

Comment: You'd have to know the *basic types of workouts* in advance, but unless the field of kinesiology changes dramatically, there's only so many of those: aerobic/cardio, weight, etc. The attributes for those basic types will be the same, or at least more similar than "workout" in general.